# My index.html file does not seem to be updating/rebuilding in my react app

Tags: html, reactjs

I have an `index_template.html` file which creates a timestamp when built then creates a duplicate index.html file in this `timestamp.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp="$(date +%s)"
echo Adding cache busting timestamp $timestamp
sed "s/%%timestamp%%/?ts=${timestamp}/g" ./build/index_template.html > ./build/index.html
```

Here is the body of my `index_template.html` file

```
<body class="">
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="./assets/js/client.bundle.js%%timestamp%%"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/vendor.js"></script>
<!-- <script>
setInterval(function() {
window.location.reload();
}, 300000);
</script> -->
</body>
```

I have commented out the script to refresh the page every 5 minutes and entered that into a few javascript files in my react app so only 3 specific pages will reload but every page is still reloading so I assume the index.html file is still running this script. I have run the commands to rebuild it in my package.json file but it is still not working. Does anyone know why?

Here are the scripts in my package.json file

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"serve": "http-server ./build -c-1",
"watch": "watchify -e ./src/index.js -o ./build/assets/js/client.bundle.js -t [ babelify ] - 
t [ envlocalify ]",
"build": "npm run compile && npm run minify && ./timestamp.sh",
"compile": "browserify -e ./src/index.js -o ./build/assets/js/client.bundle.js -t [ babelify 
] -t [ envlocalify --envfile .env.prod ]",
"minify": "uglifyjs ./build/assets/js/client.bundle.js -o ./build/assets/js/client.bundle.js 
-c -m",
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel watch serve",
"sync": "npm run build && aws s3 sync build/ s3://spark.generaltraffic.co.uk -- 
profile=genta-s3 --acl public-read --exclude 'node_modules/*|.env'"
},
```